# How to allow user to save reports from a REST API?

Tags: javascript, report, django-rest-framework

My application has to generate reports which should be available for download in XLS format. I have built a REST API using Django Rest Framework and there is an endpoint for report generation. It accepts POST requests with JSON body (report parameters, like `from`, `to`, etc., but there is also some data that represented with JSON objects) and returns JSON result. I successfully use it from Javascript, render the report as an HTML table and it works just fine.

My problem is that I need to allow users to save the report as an `.xls` file with a decent filename (like `myawesomereport.04.12-10.12.xls`. I tried JS data url approach, but as far as I understand, there is no way to set a filename if you go with that option (except setting a `download` attribute on an `a` tag, but its support is limited, so it's not the way to go). I thought that maybe I should open a new window with my API endpoint's url appropriately formed, so it outputs an XLS file, but the problem is that I do not understand if there is a way to send JSON with that request.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the filename in the backend, by using the header `Content-Disposition`, so that in the frontend you can use a standard `<a>` tag.

In DRF, it would look like this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(
    file_name
)
```

Comment: But how can I supply JSON data to this request in the first place?

Comment: It's not very common to use POST requests to download content. You could use a GET request and pass your arguments as url params.
Or you could use a POST request returning a unique link and open it using `window.open(data.url)`.